# Writelog exception error when called asynchronously

Tags: vb.net

The below code is used to log into the file "Service.27082012.txt" for today.

```
Private filePath As String
Private fileStream As FileStream
Private streamWriter As StreamWriter

Public Sub OpenFile()
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "Service." & Format(Now, "ddMMyyyy") & ".txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(strPath) Then
        fileStream = New FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
    Else
        fileStream = New FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    End If
    streamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileStream)
End Sub

Public Sub WriteLog(ByVal strComments As String)
    OpenFile()
    streamWriter.WriteLine(strComments)
    CloseFile()
End Sub

Public Sub CloseFile()
    streamWriter.Close()
    fileStream.Close()
End Sub
```

But when I try to write to the log file through Writelog asynchronously, I get the error

The process cannot access the file 'D:\Temp\Service.27082012.txt' because it is being used by another process.

How to get rid of it.

The exception stack trace is:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at Calc.Service.OpenFile() in D:\Project\Service.svc.vb:line 784
at Calc.Service.WriteLog(String strComments) in D:\Project\Service.svc.vb:line 791
at Calc.Service.GetInfo(DetailsRequest request) in D:\Project\Service.svc.vb:line 759
at SyncInvokeGetInfo(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

The log is written to the file asynchronously like below

```
Dim multiThreadOptions As ParallelOptions = New ParallelOptions
multiThreadOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16
Parallel.For(0, 100, multiThreadOptions, Function(i)
                                                 Dim objServiceCall As New ServiceCall
                                                 synw.WriteLine("{0} ", objServiceCall.MethodCall(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text))
                                                 synw.Flush()
                                                 Return i
                                             End Function)
```

The MethodCall contains the code of Writelog

```
Writelog("Comments")
```

Comment: Please show us your code how you try to write asynchronously the log file.

Comment: You would need to add a SyncLock block to avoid cross threading issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use a SyncLock to avoid cross threading issues as above. Please find sample code below:

```
Dim multiThreadOptions As ParallelOptions = New ParallelOptions
multiThreadOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16
Parallel.For(0, 100, multiThreadOptions, Function(i)
                                                 Dim objServiceCall As New ServiceCall
                                                 SyncLock synw
                                                 synw.WriteLine("{0} ", objServiceCall.MethodCall(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text))
                                                 synw.Flush()
                                                 End SyncLock
                                                 Return i
                                             End Function)
```

Also you are writing to a file that is date specific, hence if you get multiple calls in the same point of time then you would be trying to access the same file and hence you might get that exception. Try using the syncLock on the streamWriter object where you are performing the write to the file or make the log file timespecific to avoid such issues